# How to make foundation5 JS work with iron-router in meteor

Tags: meteor, zurb-foundation, iron-router

Tried all smart packages of foundation that I could find on atmosphere, but I just can't make foundation javascripts work with iron-router.

Does anyone know how to do make it work ? On first page load but also after routing to a new page.

The problem is that normally you have to call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Enable FastClick
    if(typeof FastClick !== 'undefined') {
      FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }
    $(document).foundation(function (response) {
        console.log(response.errors);
    });
});
```

But this can't work with the router

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by adding $(document).foundation() on each Template.'name'.render function.

I  haven't seen any better solution yet.